# App.OnResume error in Xamarin forms on Android and IOS devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We are using xamarin forms. After an Android or IOS device resumes from background, we are making a REST call in .net that is being triggered by a timer. The first attempt on IOS returns a "The Descriptor is not a socket" error and the Android returns a "Connection refused" error. The same code works fine in Windows. Future attempts (every few seconds) in all 3 platforms work fine. Has anyone seen this and have a fix?

Code

```cs
    //app on resume event
    protected async override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes

        if (MainPage is RootPage)
        {
            RootPage mainPage = MainPage as RootPage;
            if (mainPage.Detail is NavigationPage)
            {
                NavigationPage nvPage = mainPage.Detail as NavigationPage;
                if(nvPage.CurrentPage is ThingsPage)
                {
                    ThingsPage thPage = nvPage.CurrentPage as ThingsPage;
                    thPage.TurnOnTimer();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //code on the page
    public void TurnOnTimer()
    {
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.ContinueTimer = true;
            viewModel.StartAnotherTimer();
        }
    }

    //code in view model
    public async void StartAnotherTimer()
    {
        while (ContinueTimer)
        {
            try
            {
                DevicesUpdate devicesUpdate = await DataSource.GetDevices(LocationID, ControllerID, lastDevicesUpdateReceivedAt);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            // Update the UI (because of async/await magic, this is still in the UI thread!)
            if (ContinueTimer)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            }
        }
    }

   public static async Task<DevicesUpdate> GetDevices(Guid locationID, Guid controllerID, DateTime lastUpdateReceivedAt)
    {

          DevicesUpdate devicesUpdate = await GetLastUpdatedDevices(controllerID, lastUpdateReceivedAt);
   }

    //code in view model
    public static async Task<DevicesUpdate> GetLastUpdatedDevices(Guid controllerID, 
                                                              DateTime lastUpdate)
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    string url = string.Format("http://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/devices?controllerid={1}&lastUpdate={2}"
                                , Constants.WebServerURL, controllerID, lastUpdate);
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        DevicesUpdate devices = JSONHelper.Deserialize<DevicesUpdate>(result);
        return devices;
    }
    else
    {
        if (response.ReasonPhrase == "UserException")
        {
            throw new UserException(result);
        }
        else
        {
            //throw error because the response from rest api is not a success
            throw new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing this in the App.Resume event? Can you add a small code snippet that would explain your problem?

Comment: Yes..it is in the app.resume event. We are using the .net HttpClient to make the call to the REST service. It's a standard Client.GetAsync() call to an HTTP url. The code is in a PCL.

Comment: Can you update the question and post a code snippet of your `App.OnResume` method and your underlying service call (if it's not all directly in that method).

Comment: Does that service call work when it's not in the `App.OnResume`?

Comment: I have added code snippet to the question

Comment: @valdetero: On resume I am calling a method as mentioned above which is inside a timer implemented using await Task.Delay. This is the line that calls the method to get data from rest service:  
`DevicesUpdate devicesUpdate = await DataSource.GetDevices(LocationID, ControllerID, lastDevicesUpdateReceivedAt);`
The stack trace shows that the source of the error, is GetLastUpdatedDevices => GetDevices => StartTimer

Comment: @valdetero on two Android phones and IPad the error occurs on resume, and one of the android phone i.e. Samsung J1, the error occurs anytime when app is running (as page has timer to refresh data) and that's intermittent

Comment: @DNitke can you post the `OnResume` code? Your HTTP service call code above looks ok.

Comment: @DNitke Can you put the full url that your service calls in the browser and get back a valid response (to exclude the endpoint being the problem)?

Comment: @valdetero I have added OnResume code to the question, yes I can put the full url of service call in browser and it works, i.e. it returns valid response. Actually the service call works on two android phones and IPad until app goes background. The rest call fails on resume for first time and then it starts working back after on resume first call to rest service

Answer (score 0):

You might have a few things happening here that's causing problems.

- GetDevices doesn't return anything. (I hope you just left out the return for brevity sake)
- You are never setting `ContinueTimer` to false.
- What iOS version are you on? In later versions, you HAVE to use HTTPS or explicitly allow non-secure connections. This shouldn't be a problem because Azure has ssl.
- If you plan on running this in the background, you need to register your app as a background process.
- If you don't plan on running this in the background, you might have issues with previous attempts being ran (or still trying to execute, or just have failed) and then calling more.

What is the reason for calling the 3 second timer for the network calls? What if the call takes more than 3 seconds (then you are making duplicate calls even though the first **might** succeed).

If you want to make your network calls more robust, check out this [Blog Post by Rob Gibbons](http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/) about resilient network calls.

First thing I would do is remove it from the timer because it seems like the underlying sockets are having issues cross-thread.

Comment: 1. GetDevices does return devicesUpdate object, I have not included it here, as there is lot of code in GetDevices 2. ContinueTimer is set to false in two cases, one is OnDisappearing event of  page & other is OnSleep event of App. 3. IPad has 9.3.4 iOS version 4. I want the page data to refresh when user is on the screen not when the app goes background, and the timer code is in Xamarin forms ViewModel to refresh data.

Comment: 5. In the timer method, I have an await call to GetDevices and then await Task.Delay for 3 secs, so first the code will wait for GetDevices and when will wait for 3 secs and after 3 secs next call to GetDevices will be made, so in this case I don't think there will be duplicate calls? Second call will not be made until first call has not complete, and I am getting the data based on date and time to look and returning the updated data based on date and time